# Internet not working in LAN, Ubuntu 11.10

Tags: 11.10, internet

I have two Ethernet cards. I'm using broadband in one slot and shared network in another.
My problem is that in shared network, Internet access is not working. Google products open and work, but except for Google, it's not working.

Comment: Can include the iconfig output?

Answer (score 0):

as Mitch mentions post your ifconfig output.

Also, make sure those files are not cached for you.
Try pinging to Universal DNS like 4.2.2.2